# Group rows into two types depending on a value in column

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table:

```
------------------------------------------
Uid | mount | category 
-----------------------------------------
1   | 10    |    a
1   |  3    |    b
3   |  7    |    a
4   |  1    |    b
4   | 12    |    a
4   |  5    |    b
1   |  2    |    c
2   |  5    |    d
```

I want to have one result like this:

```
------------------------------------------
Uid | suma | sumnota
-----------------------------------------
 1  |  10  |    5    
 2  |   0  |    5
 3  |   7  |    0
 4  |  12  |    6
```

Group by uid;
Suma is sum(mount) where catagory = 'a';
Sumnota is sum(mount) where catagory <> 'a';

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation with `CASE` statements in `SUM()` function:

```
SELECT
    uid
  , SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'a' THEN mount ELSE 0 END) AS suma
  , SUM(CASE WHEN category IS DISTINCT FROM 'a' THEN mount ELSE 0 END) AS sumnota
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY uid
ORDER BY uid
```

I'm using [`IS DISTINCT FROM`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from) clause to properly handle `NULL` values in category column. If that's not your case you could simply use `<>` operator.

From [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) (**bold emphasis mine**):

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying "unknown"), not
> true or false, when either input is null.
>
> For non-null inputs, IS DISTINCT FROM is the same as the <> operator. However, if both inputs are null it returns false, and **if only one input is null it returns true**.

Comment: Thank you! It's work!
I have another case similar with this problem. The tables are two, joining this two table with same problem. But, later if I could'nt solved by my self, I will ask again. Thanks!

Comment: Approach doesn't change. Figure out your grouping, your cases and what your calculated (in this case summed) column is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution more "verbosed" than accepted answer.

```
   WITH
      t_suma AS    ( SELECT uid, SUM(mount) AS suma
                     FROM your_table  
                     WHERE category = 'a' 
                     GROUP BY uid ),
      t_sumnota AS ( SELECT uid, SUM(mount) AS sumnota 
                     FROM your_table 
                     WHERE category <> 'a' or category is NULL
                     GROUP BY uid )
    SELECT distinct y.uid, COALESCE( suma, 0) AS suma, COALESCE( sumnota, 0 ) AS sumnota
    FROM your_table y LEFT OUTER JOIN t_suma    ON ( y.uid = t_suma.uid )
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN t_sumnota ON ( y.uid = t_sumnota.uid ) 
    ORDER BY uid;
```